# perl LDAP entry not recognised

Tags: perl, active-directory, netldap

We are writing a Perl code (to be run from Unix) which will reset the password of a Windows AD User. (We are not using powershell as we have been asked not to use Windows scripts).

With the following Perl code, we are able to connect to the AD User directory and query the correct user.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#########################
#This script resets the password in active user directory 
#########################

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Net::LDAP;
use Net::LDAPS;
use Authen::SASL qw(Perl);
use Net::LDAP::Control::Paged;
use Time::Local;

my $CERTDIR     = "<cert path>";
my $AD_PASS     = "$CERTDIR/.VDIAD_pass";
my $sAN = "vahmed";

### Generate Random Password ###
my $randompass = askPasswd();
my $uninewpass;
my $mail;
my $fullname;
my $name;
my $distName;
my $finalresult;


my @AD_passwords = get_domain_pass();

my $result = reset_AD_Password();

#Reset AD user password
sub reset_AD_Password {                              
    my $ad = Net::LDAP->new($AD_passwords[0]);
    my $msg = $ad->bind(dn => "cn=$AD_passwords[2],$AD_passwords[1]",
                        password   => $AD_passwords[3],
                        version    => 3);

    if ($msg->code)
    {
            print "Error :" . $msg->error() . "\n";
            exit 2;
    }

    my $acc_name            = 'sAMAccountName';
    my $acc_fullname        = 'displayName';
    my $acc_base            = 'manager';
    my $acc_distName        = 'distinguishedName';
    my $acc_mail            = 'mail';

    my $act = $ad->search(
                        base    => "$AD_passwords[1]",
                        filter  => "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$sAN))",
                        attrs   => [$acc_name, $acc_fullname, $acc_distName, $acc_mail]);
    die 1 if ($act->count() !=1 );
my $samdn = $act->entry(0)->dn;

$fullname = $samdn->get_value($acc_fullname);
$mail = $samdn->get_value($acc_mail);   

    }
}
```

However we get an error on the line:

```
$fullname = $samdn->get_value($acc_fullname);
    $mail = $samdn->get_value($acc_mail);
```

The error states "Can't locate object method "get_value" via package (distinguished Name) (perhaps you forgot to load (distinguished Name))"
  However the code works correctly when we replace **$samdn** with the following code:

```
foreach my $entry ($act->entries){
        $name           = $entry->get_value($acc_name);
        $fullname       = $entry->get_value($acc_fullname);
        $distName       = $entry->get_value($acc_distName);
        $mail           = $entry->get_value($acc_mail);
    }
```

It would appear that the code is unable to identify **$samdn** as a *Net::LDAP::Entry* record.
  We have tried typecasting **$samdn** but got the same error.
  Could someone help in resolving this issue as we would not prefer to use the for loop just in case more that one record is returned by the search?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no typecasting in Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning a Net::LDAP::Entry to `$samdn`. You are assigning the *dn* of the first entry.

```
#                         VVVV
my $samdn = $act->entry(0)->dn;
```

Get rid of that `->dn` and it should work, if `$act->entry(0)` returns a Net::LDAP::Entry.

Comment: Thank You! Completely missed that :) The code is working now after removing the `->dn`

Comment: @VivekBAhmed sometimes that happens, and it takes a step back or someone else to see the problem. Please check out [ask] to learn how to accept an answer that solved your problem.